# Hosting client-side web part from Office 365 CDN

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-tooling

`Get-SPOTenantCdnOrigins -CdnType Public` commands in Powershell gives me the following result:

```
Public CDN enabled locations:
*/MASTERPAGE
*/STYLE LIBRARY
*/CLIENTSIDEASSETS
```

It works fine in localhost enviroment. I followed all the steps from Microsoft's article on an overview of the SharePoint Framework, but to no avail. How would I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your CDN is set to allow those file types per:

To see what file types are currently allowed by the CDN, use the Get-SPOTenantCdnPolicies cmdlet:

```
 Get-SPOTenantCdnPolicies -CdnType <Public | Private>
```

If the file types you have uploaded to the CDN are not on the list you can set them per:

```
Set-SPOTenantCdnPolicy -CdnType <Public | Private> -PolicyType IncludeFileExtensions -PolicyValue "<Comma-separated list of file types>"
```

Additional information available here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-office-365-content-delivery-network-with-sharepoint-online-bebb285f-1d54-4f79-90a5-94985afc6af8

Comment: Still doesnt work